# Gráfico ggplot R printa variáveis do eixo x em gráficos não correspondentes quando uso facet_grid()

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image: O eixo x de todos os gráficos printa os nomes de países que não correspondem a região selecionada pelo gráfica]

```
asia %>% filter(region %in% c("Western Asia and Middle East","Central Asia","East Asia")) %>%
        group_by(Country) %>%
        ggplot(aes(x = Country, y = FertRate, col = Country)) +
        geom_point() +
        geom_segment(aes(x=Country, xend = Country, y = 0,yend = FertRate )) +
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
        (~ region)
```

Comment: Tente adicionar os argumentos `scales = "free"` e `space = "free"` dentro do comando facet_grid(), isto tornará a escala variável.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como apontado por @vinícius-félix nos comentários, use "free_x" nas opções `scales` (para exibir apenas os fatores do eixo X daquela faceta) e `space` (para as larguras serem proporcionais ao número de elementos) da `facet_grid`:

```
library(ggplot2)

p <- qplot(as.factor(carb), hp, data = mtcars)

p + facet_grid(~ gear)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
p + facet_grid(~ gear, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]